# how do i add a loading circular icon as it takes time to fetch data from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

> I want to show a loading button until it loads all the list items from firestore.

```
return StreamBuilder(
         
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(uid).snapshots(),
        
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
          
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return FavItem(
                uid: snapshot.data.documents[index]['uid'],
                id: snapshot.data.documents[index]['id'],
         , 
                
                
              );
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) could be what you're looking for.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection(uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ...;
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return FavItem(
            uid: snapshot.data.documents[index]['uid'],
            id: snapshot.data.documents[index]['id'],
          );
        });
      }
```

if there is no data yet this should show a circular loading spinner(customizable) else it will show a list of FavItem.

Comment: Normally `snapshot.data` can be null if the stream returns an error. Therefore it is good to check `snapshot.hasError` before.

Answer (score 0):

Decalre bool varibale

```
bool loading = false;
```

When api function starts, setState,

```
bool loading = true;
```

End of the api function, setState,

```
bool loading = false;
```

Inside widget,check if

```
!loading ? Your widget : Center(
 Child:CirculatProgressIndicator();
  )
```